# Simplifying $\frac16\cos(\frac12x)\cos(\frac32x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\frac12x)+\frac12\sin^2(\frac12x)+\frac16\sin(\frac12x)\sin(\frac32x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm solving a differential equations. I got the final answer which is $$\frac{1}{6}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)\cos\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)+\frac{1}{6}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)\sin\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right)$$

The given answer in book is $$-\frac{1}{3}\cos x$$

I'm sure they are both equal. I don't know how to simplify my answer to the given one. Hope someone can help out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\frac{1}{6}\cos(\frac{1}{2}x)\cos(\frac{3}{2}x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\frac{1}{2}x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(\frac{1}{2}x)+\frac{1}{6}\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)\sin(\frac{3}{2}x)$

Gosh, that's ugly.

Let's just throw rocks at it until it either falls apart or lumbers off.

First, let's replace $\frac 12 x$ with $y$.

$\frac{1}{6}\cos(y)\cos(3y)-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(y)+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(y)+\frac{1}{6}\sin(y)\sin(3y)$

Now we have a case if two $\cos$ multiplied together.  How can we get those to a single cosine?  We also have to $\sin$ multiplied together.

We know that $\cos (A \pm B) = \cos A\cos B \mp \sin A\sin B$.

And we have $\frac 16[\cos(y)\cos(3y) - \sin(y)\sin(3y)]$.  So that is $\frac 16[\cos (y - 3y)] = \frac 16\cos (-2y)$.

Now we could just as easily have done $\frac 16[\cos (3y - y) ] =\frac 16  \cos 2y = \frac 16 \cos (-2y)$.

So we have:

$\frac{1}{6}\cos 2y-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(y)+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(y)$

Now we have $\frac 12(-\cos^2 y + \sin^2 y)$

If we had $\cos^2 y + \sin^2 y$ we could just add them together to get $1$.  And we could do $-\cos^2 y + \sin^2 y = 1 - 2\cos^2 y$, but that won't really help us.

But note:

$\cos(A+B) = \cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B$ so $\cos(A + A) = \cos A\cos A - \sin A\sin A = \cos^2 A - \sin^2 A$ which is *exactly* our case.

So $\frac 12(-\cos^2 y + \sin^2 y) = -\frac 12(\cos^2 y - \sin^2 y) = -\frac 12 \cos 2y$.

So we have

$\frac{1}{6}\cos 2y-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2y)= -\frac 13 \cos 2y = -\frac 13 \cos x$

====

That involved knowing our trig identities forward *and backwards*.

What if we only know them forward? That is what if don't have the inspiration to see that pattern?

Well, we could do brute force going forward.

$N = \frac{1}{6}\cos(\frac{1}{2}x)\cos(\frac{3}{2}x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\frac{1}{2}x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(\frac{1}{2}x)+\frac{1}{6}\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)\sin(\frac{3}{2}x)$.  Let $y = \frac 12 x$ so

$6N = \cos y\cos 3y - 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y + \sin y \sin 3y$

Now we know the identities *forward*....

$\cos 3y = \cos (y + 2y) = \cos y\cos 2y - \sin y \sin 2y$  and $\sin 3y = \sin(y + 2y) = \sin y\cos 2y + \cos y\sin 2y$.

So we have

$\cos y\cos 3y - 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y + \sin y \sin 3y=$

$\cos y(\cos y\cos 2y - \sin y \sin 2y)- 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y+\sin y(  \sin y\cos 2y + \cos y\sin 2y)=$

$\cos^2 y \cos 2y - \cos y\sin y\sin 2y - 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y+ \sin^2 y\cos 2y + \cos y \sin y \sin 2y=$

$cos^2 y \cos 2y+ \sin^2 y\cos 2y- 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y- \cos y\sin y\sin 2y+ \cos y \sin y \sin 2y=$.

$(\cos^2 y + sin^2 y)\cos 2y  - 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y =$

$\cos 2y - 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y$.

And we have $\cos 2y = \cos (y+y)= \cos^2 y - \sin^2 y$ so

$\cos 2y - 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y=$

$\cos^2 y - \sin^2 y- 3\cos^2 y + 3\sin^2 y=$

$-2\cos^2 y + 2\sin^2 y$.

Oh, okay, I guess we *do* need to know our identities backwards.  But as we *just* did $\cos 2y = \cos^2 y - \sin^2 y$ it should still be fresh in our minds.

$-2\cos^2 y + 2\sin^2 y= -2\cos(2y)$

So we have $6N = -2\cos(2y)$ so

$N = -\frac 13 \cos x$.

Comment: Wow! Isn't $\frac{1}{6}\cos\left(\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cos x$ easier?

Comment: easier than what.  Isn't that what I did at the very beginning?

Comment: The duplication formula is hidden in very foggy arguments.

Comment: If you can see what you saw off the top of your head fine. But how is someone supposed to recognize one has that one has the components to replace $\cos a\cos b + \sin a\sin b$ with $\cos (a - b)$ in the first place?  And where the heck did your $-\frac 12 cos x$ come from.  One can just *give* the answer.  When has to explain how one saw it in the first place.  The only "foggy" arguments was pointing out how to *see* this identities in the first place.

Comment: Not starting any arguments here, but the reason why I can group the term as suggested in my answer is that I notice the coefficient $1/6$ and $-1/2$, so it is natural trying to group them in pairs. It just works well here. Your answer is detailed, though.

Comment: Good point.  I did immediately group them in pairs but didn't spell that out.  Which as the reason my answer was so long and foggy in the first place *was* to spell out how to see inspiration, I probably should have.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**
$$\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)$$
$$\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A=\cos2A$$

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is full of red herrings. Try first removing the denominators (you can multiply by $1/6$ at the end) and writing $t$ for $x/2$. You get:
$$
\cos t\cos 3t -3\cos^2t+3\sin^2t + \sin t\sin 3t
$$
You could be tempted to expand $\cos3t$ and $\sin3t$, which is of course possible, but it would be longer than needed.

Instead, loot at the terms: there is just one minus sign, which makes unlikely some form of factorization. However, you can notice that
$$
\cos t\cos 3t+\sin t\sin 3t=\cos(3t-t)=\cos2t
$$
Also
$$
\cos^2t-\sin^2t=\cos2t
$$
and this accounts for the other two terms, so
$$
\cos t\cos 3t -3\cos^2t+3\sin^2t + \sin t\sin 3t
=
\cos 2t-3\cos2t=-2\cos2t
$$
Multiply by $1/6$ and go back to $2t=x$: your expression is
$$
-\frac{1}{3}\cos x
$$